# What is the best test to estimate the correlation between binomial/categorical dataset?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, probability

I'm trying to analyze if there are correlations between binomial dataset. I have binomial data (presence/absence) of two variables in different periods and I need to know what is the best way to find some relationship. Data were taken annually from the same samples.

Comment: Are you trying to test the association between the two variables or are you trying to see how this association evolves over time?

Comment: Firstly I want to weigh the possible association between dataset. I want to apologize if I have not explained my problem! Either the fisrt and the second dataset are binomial (1= presence; 0= absence), each pair of values of two dataset were evaluated on the same samples (monitoring site). If it is possible, I want to explain how this association evolves over time

Comment: A test isn't an estimate. Which do you want - an estimate or a test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simplest measure you can think of is the plain [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient). In the case of Bernoulli variables, it is

$$\frac{P(X=1,Y=1)-P(X=1)P(Y=1)}{\sqrt{P(X=0)P(X=1)P(Y=0)P(Y=1)}}.$$

As usual, it is close to 1 when the events tend to co-occur and close to 0 when they are statistically independent. You can also use [mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information), which quantifies the departure from independence in a different way. It measures the information that the outcome of one variable brings over the outcome of the other. Unlike the correlation, it is always positive (or null if the variables are independent) and does not distinguish between ‘positive’ and ‘negative’ associations. In your case, it is a sum of 4 terms that can be represented by the usual formula.

$$\sum_{X=0,1}\sum_{Y=0,1} P(X,Y)\log\left(\frac{P(X,Y)}{P(X)P(Y)}\right).$$

You can follow over time any one of these standard measures of statistical association.